# jQuery - how to select elements not containing specific elelments

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select elements that does not contain another elements.

Let's say I have a structure like this

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="poison-pill"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `.poison-pill` can be anywhere. I need to select a `div` with either class `first` or `second` but only if it doesn't contain an element with class `poison-pill`.

Is there a more elegant way than using a function in filter?

```
$('.first, .second').filter(function(index, element) {
    return $(element).has('.poison-pill').length === 0;
});
```

I can think of using the `not` function or `:not` selector or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.not()` with `:has` selector:

```
$('.first, .second').not(':has(.poison-pill)')
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('.first, .second').not(':has(.poison-pill)').css('background','green');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="first">a</div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="poison-pill">b</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```